# Деплой для разных доменов

Tags: развертывание

Один и тот же проект находится на 2 разных доменах (`.by` и `.ru`). Изначально он делался под домен `.by`, из-за этого в файлах конфига (`.htaccess`, `sitemap.xml`) вручную прописан домен `.by`.

[image: картинка]

Проблема в том, что некоторые ассеты на сайте с доменом `.ru` загружаются с домена `.by`.

На данный момент решением вижу - вручную менять домены в конфиге, но хотелось бы это как-то автоматизировать.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно организовать логику деплоймента одного сайта под разные домены?

Comment: прошу прощения, но какое отношение имеет к этому Angular и зачем вручную писать абсолютный урл?

Comment: @overthesanity речь идет об Angular проекте, возможно кто-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой